# Network is unreachable while using BigQuery API client library for Python

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-compute-engine

I'm using [BigQuery API client library for Python](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/bigquery/v2) from Google Compute Engine. While making query it throws network unreachable error.

```
[INFO:2018-01-02 16:16:04,887:oauth2client.transport] Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
[INFO:2018-01-02 16:16:04,924:oauth2client.client] Refreshing access_token
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/test/data/reports/ga_bigquery.py", line 130, in ga_table_string
    if bq_dataset.table("ga_sessions_{}".format(str_date)).exists():
  File "/test/data/reports/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gcloud/bigquery/table.py", line 472, in exists
    query_params={'fields': 'id'})
  File "/test/data/reports/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gcloud/connection.py", line 343, in api_request
    target_object=_target_object)
  File "/test/data/reports/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gcloud/connection.py", line 241, in _make_request
    return self._do_request(method, url, headers, data, target_object)
  File "/test/data/reports/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gcloud/connection.py", line 270, in _do_request
    body=data)
  File "/test/data/reports/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/transport.py", line 153, in new_request
    credentials._refresh(orig_request_method)
  File "/test/data/reports/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 765, in _refresh
    self._do_refresh_request(http_request)
  File "/test/data/reports/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 797, in _do_refresh_request
    self.token_uri, method='POST', body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/test/data/reports/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1609, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/test/data/reports/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1351, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/test/data/reports/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1272, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "/test/data/reports/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1075, in connect
    raise socket.error, msg
socket.error: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
```

What could be the reason?

I run the code with following option :

```
[root@myserver]# strace -ff -e poll,select,connect,recvfrom,sendto python run.py --date=20180102 >> strace.log

[root@myserver]# cat strace.log | grep unreachable
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(443), inet_pton(AF_INET6, “2404:6800:4003:c02::54”, &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0}, 28) = -1 ENETUNREACH (Network isunreachable)
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(443), inet_pton(AF_INET6, “2404:6800:4003:803::200a”, &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0}, 28) = -1 ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
connect(5, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(443), inet_pton(AF_INET6, “2404:6800:4003:808::200d”, &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0}, 28) = -1 ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
connect(6, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(443), inet_pton(AF_INET6, “2404:6800:4003:c03::5f”, &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0}, 28) = -1 ENETUNREACH (Network isunreachable)
```

From log it looks like compute instance is blocking outgoing ipv6 request.
Is there any way we can unblcok ipv6 requests in google compute engine ?

Comment: A network problem?

Comment: it seems to be working for few times then it's gets stuck on then the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you are using the [BigQuery *API* Client Library for Python](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/bigquery/v2), you may want to try the [BigQuery *Cloud* Client Library for Python](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/usage.html), instead.

One reason for this could be that the *API* client library uses [httplib2](https://github.com/httplib2/httplib2) to make requests to BigQuery, which has [problems in some network setups such as behind proxies](https://github.com/httplib2/httplib2/issues/68). The *Cloud* library uses the more standard [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library, so it should be more reliable.

Second, even if you don't switch libraries, you should change what authentication library you are using. Your stack trace shows `oauth2client`, but [oauth2client is deprecated](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2client-deprecation.html). Use [google-auth-httplib2](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-auth-library-python-httplib2) to use the API client libraries with the `google-auth` library.